# Computing the exponential matrix with complex eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ two fixed parameters, and consider the following matrix $$
A:=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & -a & 0 & 0 \\ a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0&0&b \\ 0&0&b&0\end{matrix}\right).
$$
I am trying  to compute the exponential matrix $e^{Ax}$ associated with $A$ above. In order to do it, I started by computing its eigenvalues, from where I obtained $\{\pm b,\pm ia\}$, and hence $A$ is diagonalizable. Here is where everything became dark for me, specifically, the fact that I have two complex eigenvalues confuses me. For example, in order to obtain the eigenspace associated with $\pm b$, I know that I just have to solved the following system $$
(A\mp bI)\vec{v}=\vec{0},
$$
from where I obtained (respectively): $$
\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right) \qquad \hbox{and}\qquad \left( \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{matrix}\right).
$$
However, as I said before, when trying to mimic the previous computations with the eigenvalues $\pm ia$, I got confused and I blocked. For example, if I pick $+ia$, the first two equations associated with $(A-iaI)\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ writes $$
ia v_1+av_2=0 \quad \hbox{ and } \quad av_1-iav_2=0,
$$
from where I cannot solve for $v_1$ or $v_2$. Does anyone knows how to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticing that
$$
A^{2n}={\rm diag}\{(-1)^n a^{2n},(-1)^n a^{2n}, b^{2n},  b^{2n}\}
$$
and
$$
A^{2n+1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & (-1)^{n+1} a^{2n+1}& 0 & 0 \\
(-1)^{n} a^{2n+1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b^{2n+1}\\
0 & 0 &  b^{2n+1} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You can separate $e^{x A}$ into two parts
$$
e^{x A} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}+
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}
$$
The first and second summation are separately
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos (a x) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos (a x) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \cosh (b x) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \cosh (b x) \\
\end{pmatrix}
,\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -\sin (a x) & 0 & 0 \\
 \sin (a x) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \sinh (b x) \\
 0 & 0 & \sinh (b x) & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two paths to solution.

The first is as you suggest go to the diagonal form.  If $U$ is the matrix obtained from the eigenvectors of $A$ arranged in columns, then
\begin{align}
U^{-1}AU=D\, ,\qquad 
D=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
b&&&\\
&-b&&\\
&&ia&\\
&&&-ia\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
e^A &= 1+UDU^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}UD^2U^{-1}+\ldots \, ,\\
&= U \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
e^b&&&\\
&e^{-b}&&\\
&&e^{ia}&\\
&&&e^{-ia}\end{array}\right) U^{-1}\, 
\end{align}

The second path is to observe that your $A$ is actually block diagonal and that it's
easy to take powers of each block since (for instance)
\begin{align}
\tilde a&= a\sigma\, ,\qquad \sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&-1\\ 1&0\end{array}\right)\, ,\\
\tilde a^2 &= - a^2 1\, ,\qquad \tilde a^3=- a^3\sigma \ldots
\end{align}
so that, for instance, the exponentiation of this submatix gives
\begin{align}
e^{\tilde a}&= \left(1-\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{a^4}{4!}+\ldots\right)
+ \sigma \left(a - \frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{a^5}{5!}+\ldots\right)\,  \\
\end{align}
and you can recompose the sums into trigonometric functions.

The same reasoning applied to the submatrix containing $b$ entries except that
this time $\Sigma=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\ 1&0\end{array}\right)$ is such that $\Sigma^2=1, \Sigma^3=\Sigma$ etc so that $e^{\tilde b}$ will recompose in terms of hyperbolic sine and cosine.